# Why are my multi-state boxes not working after including SendGrid code in my Wix Velo E-Learning Calculator

Tags: velo

Problem in wix velo code, while using multi-state boxes.

I'm currently developing an elearning calculator which on answering the questions, mails the users the summary of the calculations, using wix multi-state boxes, velo code and SendGrid for sending the emails. I've written the code for the multi-state boxes myself and referred chatgpt and SendGrid documentation for the rest of the code. But, after incorporating the whole code, my multi-state boxes stopped working.
Below is the code-

```
import {sendEmail, sendEmailWithRecipient} from 'backend/email';
//question1 - Course length
$w.onReady(function () { 
    let courseLength;
    let devTime;
    let devCost;
   
//    function getCourseLength() {
      
       $w('#radio1click').onClick(() => {  
        $w('#opt1statebox').changeState("opt1expanded");
        $w('#opt2statebox').changeState("opt2collapsed");
        $w('#opt3statebox').changeState("opt3collapsed");
        $w('#opt4statebox').changeState("opt4collapsed");
        $w('#tipstatebox').changeState("opt1state");
       courseLength = parseInt($w('#iltInput').value) * 60;
    })
    
    $w('#radio2click').onClick(() => {
        $w('#opt2statebox').changeState("opt2expanded");
        $w('#opt1statebox').changeState("opt1collapsed");
        $w('#opt3statebox').changeState("opt3collapsed");
        $w('#opt4statebox').changeState("opt4collapsed");
        $w('#tipstatebox').changeState("opt2state");
         let words = parseInt($w('#scriptInput').value);
        courseLength = Math.round(words * 0.006666666666666667);
    })

    $w('#radio3click').onClick(() => {
        $w('#opt3statebox').changeState("opt3expanded");
        $w('#opt1statebox').changeState("opt1collapsed");
        $w('#opt2statebox').changeState("opt2collapsed");
        $w('#opt4statebox').changeState("opt4collapsed");
        $w('#tipstatebox').changeState("opt3state");
        let slides = parseInt($w('#slideInput').value);
       courseLength = Math.round(slides * 0.45454545454545453);
    })

    $w('#radio4click').onClick(() => {
        $w('#opt4statebox').changeState("opt4expanded");
        $w('#opt1statebox').changeState("opt1collapsed");
        $w('#opt2statebox').changeState("opt2collapsed");
        $w('#opt3statebox').changeState("opt3collapsed");
        $w('#tipstatebox').changeState("opt4state");
       courseLength = parseInt($w('#courseLengthInput').value);
    })
//    }
        

    //next and back buttons
    $w('#nextstate1').onClick(() => {
        $w('#mainstatebox').changeState("State2");
    })
    
    $w('#backstate2').onClick(() => {
        $w('#mainstatebox').changeState("State1");
    })
    $w('#nextstate2').onClick(() => {
        $w('#mainstatebox').changeState("State3");
    })
    $w('#backstate3').onClick(() => {
        $w('#mainstatebox').changeState("State2");
    })
    $w('#nextstate3').onClick(() => {
        $w('#mainstatebox').changeState("State4");
    })
    $w('#backstate4').onClick(() => {
        $w('#mainstatebox').changeState("State3");
    })
    
    //question 2 -Development Time

    function getDevelopmentTime() {
        $w('#radioGroup25').onChange(() => {
         if ($w("#radioGroup25").value==="1") {
              $w('#statebox9').changeState("level1");
    }
         if ($w("#radioGroup25").value==="1.5") {
              $w('#statebox9').changeState("level1o5");
    }
         if ($w("#radioGroup25").value==="2") {
              $w('#statebox9').changeState("level2");
    }
         if ($w("#radioGroup25").value==="2.5") {
              $w('#statebox9').changeState("level2o5");
    }
         if ($w("#radioGroup25").value==="3") {
              $w('#statebox9').changeState("level3");
    }
  
    })
    }
    

   //question 3- Development Cost

   function getDevelopmentCost() {
        $w('#radiocontractorC').onChange(() => {
        $w('#contractorstate').changeState("Cexpanded");
        $w('#employeestate').changeState("Ecollapsed");
        
    })
    $w('#radioemployeeC').onChange(() => {
        $w('#contractorstate').changeState("Ccollapsed");
        $w('#employeestate').changeState("Eexpanded");
    })
   }

     
// function to send summary email to user
  
function sendFormData() {
  const subject = `E-Learning Calculator`;
  const body =  `Course Length: ${courseLength} minutes `;
  const recipient = $w("#emailInput").value;
 
  sendEmailWithRecipient(subject, body, recipient)
    .then(response => console.log(response)); 
}
});
```

[here is the image of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrmXI.png)
Each radio button is a seperate multi-state box, on clicking which expands to a specific input text box, that is further used in the sendFormData function to email the users. I've just tried it for the first question. I need to input courselength from the function getCourseLength and return it, so that I can use it in the email function. But I am unable to incorporate this idea. Currently, neither the email function is working nor am I able to return the courselength.  Could someone please tell me why are my multi-state boxes not working after incorporating the further code?